# Show h2 tag ONLY if there is a description in product category in Woocommerce

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-taxonomy

Our Woocommerce product category archive pages have an `<h1>` tag at the top followed by the grid of products as by default.

Now we have added an `<h2>` tag with the category name again at the bottom and under the `<h2>` tag is the description for that product category.

I have set this up in the `archive-product.php` adding this:

```
<h2 class="cat-desc-title"><?php woocommerce_page_title(); ?></h2>
```

However I was wondering if anyone knew a way to show this ONLY if there is a description displayed on this product category page.

How to write an `if` statement for that?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you access the content variable?

Comment: I'm not sure where to look leme see

Comment: <?php echo $term_object->description; ?> - possibly?

Comment: I got that from this link. Where he describes how to add the description I am talking about. 

https://davidnash.com.au/woocommerce-category-description/

Answer (score 3):

Yes this is possible adding some condition in an `if` statement like:

```
    <?php 
        if ( is_product_taxonomy() && 0 === absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ):

        $wp_term_obj = get_queried_object();

        if ( $wp_term_obj && ! empty( $wp_term_obj->description ) ):
    ?>

        <h2 class="woocommerce-products-header__title page-title"><?php woocommerce_page_title(); ?></h2>

    <?php endif; endif; ?>
```

This will display your `<h2>` title only if a description exist for the  queried product category (or the product tag). This goes in `archive-product.php`. It  is tested and works.

Now if you want to target specifically product category archives pages (but not product tag archives), you will replace `is_product_taxonomy()` by `is_product_category()`.

---

**Alternative Without overriding template files:**

> This could be embed in a hooked function instead of overriding the template, just as the displayed product category description, with a hook priority before `10`.

So this could be done with something like:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description', 'add_h2_title_before_archive_description', 5 );
function add_h2_title_before_archive_description() {
    if ( is_product_taxonomy() && 0 === absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ):
        $wp_term_obj = get_queried_object();

        if ( $wp_term_obj && ! empty( $wp_term_obj->description ) ):
        ?>
        <h2 class="woocommerce-products-header__title page-title"><?php woocommerce_page_title(); ?></h2>
        <?php
        endif; 
    endif;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).

Tested and works.